# Case sensitivity in bundle Identifier and the product name

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, xcode5

I'm creating a new project in xCode with the following name "SampleApp"
Bundle identifier becomes like this "com.samplecompany.SampleApp" (Last word has camel casing)
But the App Id in the developer portal is "com.sampleCompany.sampleapp" (All lower case letters).

So, whenever I archive and try to sign a build with the provisioning profile, xCode says that the provisioning profile with the mentioned bundle identifier(com.samplecompany.SampleApp) is not found.(Since the app id is in all lower case format in the developer portal).

I tried to create the app id, "com.samplecompany.SampleApp", but the developer portal throws an error "com.samplecompany.SampleApp" is already taken.

If I go with all lowercase, My app name also becomes lower case.
My app is already in the appstore with all lower cases. So, I'm worried, if I remove the profile and re-create it, it will cause problems in the appstore build.

I'm struck here. How to solve this issue ?

Comment: Paste this bundle id in plist "com.sampleCompany.sampleapp".

Comment: it shoud be same as the app id given in provisional profile

Answer (score 1):

Apple [AppDistributionGuide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/ConfiguringYourApp/ConfiguringYourApp.html) says,

> If the App ID is an explicit App ID, it exactly matches the bundle
>   ID. However, unlike domain names, bundle IDs are case sensitive. If
>   the App ID is lowercase, your bundle ID needs to be lowercase, too

**Note:** bundle ID is not what the user will see as the app name. That's the "Bundle Display Name".

Answer (score 1):

The bundle ID is case sensitive. we need to use the app Id and bundle identifier are same. check the [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/ConfiguringYourApp/ConfiguringYourApp.html)

The bundle ID is not what the user will see as the app name. That's the "**Bundle Display Name**".You can change the Bundle Display Name to change the icon name displayed in home screen.